# Can I hook up an Analog multiplexer to Arduino Nano?

Tags: arduino-nano, analogread, multiplexer

I want to increase the analogue inputs for the Nano. So is it possible to hook up a CD74HC4067 analog multiplexer to it?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is. Just follow one of the myriad of tutorials that show you how, or find plenty of questions on here that deal with it.

Comment: [This answer](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/36931/31794) discusses that exact chip.

Answer (score -1):

> yes. those using IO expanders offers more flexibility.

Comment: IO expanders are for digital, not analog.